# SendKeys.send is sending a key, but the application is not interpreting this key as a command

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I'm using `SendKeys` to send key strokes to a program.

This is my code:

```
   If whandle <> 0 Then
        User32.SetForegroundWindow(whandle)
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("+")
    End If
```

*(I tried also `SendWait()` instead of `Send()`)*

This is my window hierachy shown by Spy++:

[image: Spy++ window hierachy]

Althoug I can find window handle by title and loop through childs with `User32.FindWindowEx`, when debugging I just enter window handle as shown by spy++ (converting from hex to decimal) and I find that:

- Correct window is found and brought to front.
- But nothing happens with this particular program, called MetaTrader (if I use a notepad window keys are written in notepad).

So I guess I have one of these problems:

1. I'm doing something wrong with windows and subwindows (I don't really think this is happening as I tried all handles shown by Spy++).
2. SendKey("+") is not exactly like pressing the "+" key when window is active and there is some difference.

After calling to `User32.SetForegroundWindow(whandle)` if I really press the "+" key the desired effect happens, which is a zoom in, but not when it's my program doing `SendKeys`. I tried also with other keys that produce commands, like Q or A (all of them simple keys and letters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=net-5.0)

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
> parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
> these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
> specify the plus sign, use "{+}"

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{+}")
```